# Display a text word by word slowly in swift

Tags: swift, string, delay

swift 5 iOS 13

Trying to print out a sentence word by word slowly. Drafted this code that works, but I fear I am going to crash the phone with too many threads if I feed in a sentence that is too long.

```
    let textFeed = "Some text message made up of words"
    var second = 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {

      for word in textFeed.components(separatedBy: " ") {
        var delay = DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(second)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {
          self.infoText2.text = String(word)

          print("word",word,second)
        })
        second = second + 1
      }
    })
```

Any thoughts on doing this differently, less threads?

Comment: check my answer maybe it helps

Answer (score 2):

a simple rekusive func

```
printMessage(message: "I am a test")

func printMessage(message: String?, delay: TimeInterval = 1) {
        let splits = message?.split(separator: " ", maxSplits: 1)
        print(splits?.first)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {[weak self] in
            guard splits?.count == 2 else {
                return
            }
            self?.printMessage(message: String(splits?.last ?? ""))
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i have this piece of code

```
extension String {
var characterArray: [Character]{
    var characterArray = [Character]()
    for character in self {
        characterArray.append(character)
    }
    return characterArray
}
}

extension UITextView {
func typeOn(string: String) {
    let characterArray = string.characterArray
    var characterIndex = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        self.text.append(characterArray[characterIndex])
        characterIndex += 1
        if characterIndex == characterArray.count {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
}

// and in your view controller you just call it like this 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let msg:String = "test"
    youtextView.typeOn(string: msg)
}
```

Comment: string.characterArray doesn't seem to exist on iOS 13 under swift 5.x.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot something check the edited answer

Comment: I would vote this as the accepted answer, but it is based on a textview ultimately and I got a UILabel. I rewrote it and posted a new solution based on it!

Comment: @user3069232 weird its working for me why its not working for you for ios 13

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer given by [Was'Siim Ben Hssen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6073064/wassiim-ben-hssen), only this one uses a UILabel.

```
let textFeed = "print out words one by one slowly"

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
    let words = textFeed.components(separatedBy: " ")
    var i = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
          self.infoText2.text = String(words[i])
          self.infoText.text = self.infoText.text! + String(words[i]) + " "
          if i == words.count - 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
          } else {
            i = i + 1
          }
    }
    })
```

Change these two lines to get a character by character reveal.

```
//        let words = textFeed.components(separatedBy: " ")
          let words = Array(textFeed)
//        self.infoText.text = self.infoText.text! + String(words[i]) + " "
          self.infoText.text = self.infoText.text! + String(words[i])
```

Comment: And it works better than my original one did! THANKS Was'Siim!

Comment: the first solution is working for me why its not for you ? you found the issue ?

Comment: The first solution launches a new thread for every word as did mine. It had a massive overhead.